# React how to close a popover with a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popover, react-bootstrap

With [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#overlays), I have a popover that contains a list. On click of one of the list items, it opens a modal.

How to close the popover when the modal is opening?

I tried:

- `rootClose` but it's not working
- [React Bootstrap - How to
  manually close OverlayTrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467848/react-bootstrap-how-to-manually-close-overlaytrigger), that close both, the popover and the modal

  ```
  class TypeColumn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
      this.close = this.close.bind(this);
  }

  close() {
      this.refs.overlay.hide();
  }

  render() {
      const popoverClick = (
          <Popover id="popover-trigger-click-root-close">
              <ul>
                  <NumberOptions onClick={this.close} />
              </ul>
          </Popover>
      );

      return (
          <OverlayTrigger
              show={show}
              trigger="click"
              placement="bottom"
              overlay={popoverClick}
              ref="overlay"
          >
              <i
                  className={columnTypeIcon} aria-hidden="true"
              />
          </OverlayTrigger>
      );
  }
  }

  class NumberOptions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.open = this.open.bind(this);

      this.state = {
          showModal: false,
      };
  }

  open() {
      this.setState({ showModal: true });
      this.props.onClick();
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <li
                  data-value={DATA_TYPES.NUMBER}
                  onClick={this.open}
              >
                  Options nombre
              </li>

              <Modal
                show={showModal}
                dialogClassName={styles.customModal}
              >
              ...
              </Modal>
          </div>
      );
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: Show the code, what you have used, please.

Comment: @Andrew I've added the code, any ideas?

Comment: You need to move `Modal` from `NumberOptions` it should be at least on the same level as `OverlayTrigger`.

Comment: @Andrew it works, thank you. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Pleased to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your component `Modal` is a child of `NumberOptions`, `Modal` is closing too when `NumberOptions` is closing.

So you need to lift `Modal` component at least to the same level as `OverlayTrigger`.